# Unable to connect to Google Bigtable using HBase REST api

Tags: python, hbase, google-cloud-bigtable

Following [this example](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-rest-client), running the test script "python put_get_with_client.py" results in a 400 error (Bad Request).

> Bad request
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BigtableConnection cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClusterConnection
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:410)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:370)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:197)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ConnectionCache.getCurrentConnection(ConnectionCache.java:170)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ConnectionCache.getAdmin(ConnectionCache.java:124)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.RESTServlet.getAdmin(RESTServlet.java:102)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.RootResource.getTableList(RootResource.java:64)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.RootResource.get(RootResource.java:80)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.filter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:76)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>       at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
>       at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

So, I guess BigtableConnection does not implement the ClusterConnection interface?  Is the example correct?

Comment: I'll ping someone on this -- try to get you an answer soon.

Comment: Some patches we were expecting in 1.0.1 of HBase didn't make it.  We are trying to figure out a work-a-round.  Someone will post to this when we understand what we can do -- probably not before Monday, however.

Comment: Our changes got to the HBase 2.x fork, but not 1.0.x or 1.x.  We hope to open source our changes (hopefully next week), and may also include a binary.

Comment: The two patches we've submitted around this are: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-13664 & https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-12993

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments above, we have submitted patches to the Apache HBase project to fix ReST and Thrift -- they've also been accepted and integrated.  While we wait for a release which incorporates them to be release, we've released a [temporary fork of 1.0.1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/releases/tag/v0.1.5) to help you work with this.  We will be removing this fork as soon as these changes are incorporated.