# Cannot connect from Titan to Google Bigtable via Hbase client

Tags: hbase, titan, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to connect to Titan 1.0.0 with Hadoop 2 (HBase 1.0.2 client) (available in https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Downloads) with Google Cloud Bigtable service, using its HBase client.

I could successfully connect to Bigtable from an HBase shell in a GCE instance, by following [this procedure](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/installing-hbase-shell). The `hbase-site.xml` is according to the template, and I have downloaded Bigtable jars for `ALPN_VERSION=8.1.5.v20150921` (Oracle JDK SE 1.8.0_60)

```xml
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.connection.impl</name>
    <value>com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_0.BigtableConnection</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>google.bigtable.cluster.name</name>
    <value>[YOUR-CLUSTER-ID]</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>google.bigtable.project.id</name>
    <value>[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>google.bigtable.zone.name</name>
    <value>[YOUR-ZONE-NAME]</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Then, I copied `hbase-site.xml` to `titan-1.0.0-hadoop2/conf` directory, and Bigtable jars to `titan-1.0.0-hadoop2/lib` folder.

Then, on `titan-1.0.0-hadoop2` folder, I run `./run/gremlin.sh` and start the console.

Therefore, when trying to create a connection using HBase client (configured to point out to Bigtable cluster)...

```
TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "hbase").open();
```

...I get the following exception in the Gremlin console:

```
com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_0.BigtableConnection cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClusterConnection
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
gremlin> TitanFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "hbase").open();

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/titan-1.0.0-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/titan-1.0.0-hadoop2/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
13:42:24 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13:42:25 WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager  - Unexpected exception during getDeployment()
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_0.BigtableConnection cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClusterConnection
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.(HBaseAdmin.java:225)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HConnection1_0.getAdmin(HConnection1_0.java:28)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getAdminInterface(HBaseStoreManager.java:960)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.ensureTableExists(HBaseStoreManager.java:747)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getLocalKeyPartition(HBaseStoreManager.java:556)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getDeployment(HBaseStoreManager.java:347)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getFeatures(HBaseStoreManager.java:389)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1321)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:84)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:139)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder$open$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:114)
    at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:94)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.(Console.groovy:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:303)
13:42:25 WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager  - Unexpected exception during getDeployment()
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_0.BigtableConnection cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClusterConnection
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.(HBaseAdmin.java:225)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HConnection1_0.getAdmin(HConnection1_0.java:28)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getAdminInterface(HBaseStoreManager.java:960)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.ensureTableExists(HBaseStoreManager.java:747)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getLocalKeyPartition(HBaseStoreManager.java:556)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getDeployment(HBaseStoreManager.java:347)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getFeatures(HBaseStoreManager.java:389)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStandaloneGlobalConfiguration(Backend.java:438)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1322)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:84)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:139)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder$open$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:114)
    at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:94)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.(Console.groovy:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:303)
13:42:25 WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager  - Unexpected exception during getDeployment()
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_0.BigtableConnection cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClusterConnection
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.(HBaseAdmin.java:225)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HConnection1_0.getAdmin(HConnection1_0.java:28)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getAdminInterface(HBaseStoreManager.java:960)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.ensureTableExists(HBaseStoreManager.java:747)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getLocalKeyPartition(HBaseStoreManager.java:556)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getDeployment(HBaseStoreManager.java:347)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getFeatures(HBaseStoreManager.java:389)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.common.AbstractStoreManager.getMetaDataSchema(AbstractStoreManager.java:44)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseKeyColumnValueStore.(HBaseKeyColumnValueStore.java:67)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.openDatabase(HBaseStoreManager.java:446)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.KeyColumnValueStoreManager.openDatabase(KeyColumnValueStoreManager.java:29)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStandaloneGlobalConfiguration(Backend.java:449)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1322)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:84)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:139)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder$open$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:114)
    at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:94)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.(Console.groovy:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:303)
com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_0.BigtableConnection cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClusterConnection
```

I've found other question with the same exception in other context: [Unable to connect to Google Bigtable using HBase REST api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131439/unable-to-connect-to-google-bigtable-using-hbase-rest-api) .
Would that patch also solve this exception I am getting with Titan?

Comment: My understanding is that Titan is currently using an HBase before 1.0. Cloud Bigtable requires at least HBase 1.0 or greater.  It's also my understanding that an update is in progress.

Comment: Thanks Les Vogel! I am using **Titan 1.0.0 with Hadoop 2** distribution available [here](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Downloads), which actually uses **HBase 1.0.2 client**.
I would be great to have a managed Google BigTable cluster as backend for Titan!

Comment: cool - I'll spend some time on this, this weekend.  Hope you don't mind if I set it up using Cloud Dataproc?

Comment: Great to hear from you Les. You may set it up using Dataproc, sure.

Comment: Didn't get to it this weekend, will try again on Friday.

Comment: Still on this - results probably on Wednesday.

Comment: Hi Les, could you reproduce the problem? Let me know. Cheers

Comment: Basically, you can't use new HBaseAdmin() with Cloud Bigtable.  You have to use Connection.getAdmin().  This will require (relatively minor) changes in the titan hbase 1.0 code.

Answer (score 4):

Titan is no longer maintained; however, you can use [JanusGraph](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph) (a fork of Titan) together with [Google Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/); see the following guides for details:

- [running JanusGraph with Cloud Bigtable on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/running-janusgraph-with-bigtable)
- [configuring JanusGraph to connect to Cloud Bigtable](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/bigtable.html)

GitHub hosts the [JanusGraph releases](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/).